Trouble rendering 3d mesh in vulkan
I need to render a 3d mesh in Vulkan. I want even the 'inside/hidden' edges to show up. For example, this is a tetrahedron, but without the 'hidden' edge.

This is the same tetra from another angle:

I want to be able to see the edge even from the first viewing angle.
I have my depth test disabled through :
depthStencil.depthTestEnable = VK_FALSE; 
depthStencil.depthWriteEnable = VK_FALSE;

and fillModeNonSolid is enabled.
deviceFeatures.fillModeNonSolid = VK_TRUE;

The topology is set as :
inputAssembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;

I am working on a Mac.
I am not sure what other part of configuration I am missing.

Have you disabled face culling?

Thanks. It worked.
Trying to hack my way through Vulkan.
